# AnyChart - Live Streaming Stock Chart

Tags: anychart

I call a database that gives me the initial time interval data to create a OHLC stock chart in AnyChart. Live price updates are then streamed.

What is the strategy about showing live price changes on the latest ticker?

I've been trying to figure out how to use a set function from the view or data class but no luck with table data.

Should I keep track of this newest interval and keep updating this row in AnyChart? When the interval is finished I drop the last one from the series and generate a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I caught your idea correctly, you're looking for an approach like the following one:

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

    /*
    An interval ticker and random number generators simulate incoming data.
  For the demonstration purposes the time is “accelerated”.
    */

    //create new point every 1 minute
    var period = 60000;
    //new price ticks come every 15 seconds
    var tickPeriod = 15000;

    var stage = anychart.graphics.create("container");

    // create and tune the chart
    var chart = anychart.stock();
    var plot = chart.plot();
    
    grouping = chart.grouping();

    //create OHLC series
    var ohlcSeries = plot.ohlc().name('OHLC');

    // create dataset
    var dataset = anychart.data.table();
    dataset.addData(getData());

    //map data
    var mapping = dataset.mapAs({
        x: 0,
        open: 1,
        high: 2,
        low: 3,
        close: 4
    });

    //set mapping to both series
    ohlcSeries.data(mapping);

    //render chart
    chart.container(stage).draw();

    /* --- simulation code --- */

    //create empty array for point data update
    var newDataRow = [];
    newDataRow[0] = new Array(5);
    //current price variable
    var price = null;

    //select the last point from existing datatable
    var selectable = mapping.createSelectable();
    selectable.selectAll();
    var iterator = selectable.getIterator();

    while(iterator.advance()) {
        //put data from the last exsiting point
        newDataRow[0][0] = iterator.get('x');
        newDataRow[0][1] = iterator.get('open');
        newDataRow[0][2] = iterator.get('high');
        newDataRow[0][3] = iterator.get('low');
        newDataRow[0][5] = iterator.get('close');
    }
    //timestamp variable for incoming ticks
    var newTimestamp = newDataRow[0][0];

    //simulate price ticker
    window.setInterval(stream, 500);

    //updating chart handler
    function stream() {
        //get new price
        price = randomPrice();
        //get timestamp of incoming price tick
        newTimestamp += tickPeriod;

        //current point update or create new point
        if (newTimestamp - newDataRow[0][0] <= period) {
            //set price as close for existing point
            newDataRow[0][4] = price;
            //update min and max
            if (newDataRow[0][2] < price) {
                newDataRow[0][2] = price;
            } else if (newDataRow[0][3] > price) {
                newDataRow[0][3] = price;
            }
        } else {
            //erase update data array
            newDataRow[0] = new Array(5);
            //set data for the new point
            newDataRow[0][0] = newTimestamp;
            newDataRow[0][1] = price;
            newDataRow[0][2] = price;
            newDataRow[0][3] = price;
            newDataRow[0][4] = price;
        }
        dataset.addData(newDataRow);
    }
});

function randomPrice() {
    return (Math.random() * (24 - 22) + 22).toFixed(2);
}

function getData() {
    return [[1508889600000, 18.23, 19.36, 18.18, 19.31, 116002], [1508889660000, 19.5, 19.89, 19, 19.29, 113146], [1508889720000, 19.13, 19.15, 18.43, 18.75, 88690], [1508889780000, 18.54, 18.76, 18.27, 18.76, 80909], [1508889840000, 18.76, 19.14, 18.63, 18.76, 94782], [1508889900000, 18.97, 19.62, 18.96, 19.19, 133294], [1508889960000, 19.45, 19.7, 19.22, 19.67, 136209], [1508890020000, 19.69, 19.85, 19.37, 19.59, 136739], [1508890080000, 19.44, 19.55, 19, 19.35, 45322], [1508890140000, 19.21, 19.25, 18.51, 18.83, 37537], [1508890200000, 19.16, 19.78, 18.99, 19.76, 37994], [1508890260000, 19.69, 19.69, 19, 19.2, 114186], [1508890320000, 18.89, 18.95, 18.57, 18.61, 61185], [1508890380000, 18.59, 19.08, 18.57, 18.97, 40558], [1508890440000, 18.76, 19.19, 18.7, 18.78, 54007], [1508890500000, 18.92, 18.94, 18.47, 18.92, 65713], [1508890560000, 19.82, 21.2, 19.5, 20.91, 114016], [1508890620000, 20.55, 20.82, 20.28, 20.4, 100002], [1508890680000, 20.25, 20.27, 19.79, 19.93, 112040], [1508890740000, 20.11, 20.89, 20.06, 20.25, 106204], [1508890800000, 20.6, 21.1, 20.01, 20.26, 43234], [1508890860000, 20.19, 20.35, 19.86, 20.24, 45577], [1508890920000, 20.37, 20.4, 19.98, 20.19, 138514], [1508890980000, 20.14, 20.24, 19.64, 19.79, 15961], [1508891040000, 20.06, 20.07, 19.61, 19.79, 4816], [1508891100000, 19.96, 19.99, 19.14, 19.32, 42609], [1508891160000, 19.46, 19.64, 19.14, 19.42, 100893], [1508891220000, 19.2, 19.73, 19.01, 19.32, 106489], [1508891280000, 19.51, 20.06, 19.47, 19.89, 86507], [1508891340000, 19.92, 20, 19.67, 19.75, 122805], [1508891400000, 19.83, 20.23, 19.8, 20.06, 38734], [1508891460000, 20.13, 20.5, 19.98, 20.22, 128804], [1508891520000, 20.36, 20.6, 20.24, 20.6, 30999], [1508891580000, 20.51, 20.74, 20.25, 20.31, 45246], [1508891640000, 20.41, 20.69, 20.22, 20.38, 101014], [1508891700000, 20.14, 20.23, 19.51, 19.82, 119823], [1508891760000, 19.93, 20.17, 19.47, 19.75, 73663], [1508891820000, 19.54, 20.45, 19.45, 20.34, 56848], [1508891880000, 20.25, 20.6, 20.07, 20.13, 133059], [1508891940000, 20.32, 20.63, 20.05, 20.45, 41431], [1508892000000, 20.56, 20.94, 20.3, 20.89, 30151], [1508892060000, 21, 21.5, 20.86, 21.4, 82553], [1508892120000, 21.36, 21.98, 21.2, 21.4, 81917], [1508892180000, 21.31, 21.76, 21.29, 21.73, 52368], [1508892240000, 21.77, 21.9, 21.58, 21.83, 20181], [1508892300000, 21.96, 22.31, 21.81, 22.14, 112622], [1508892360000, 21.98, 22.32, 21.63, 22.05, 99857], [1508892420000, 22.06, 22.32, 21.88, 22.08, 105763], [1508892480000, 22.17, 22.62, 22.12, 22.55, 118968], [1508892540000, 22.59, 23.26, 22.57, 22.83, 12246], [1508892600000, 22.9, 23.38, 22.74, 23.33, 134378], [1508892660000, 23.23, 23.54, 23.02, 23.42, 117356], [1508892720000, 23.47, 24.11, 23.44, 23.45, 71104], [1508892780000, 23.5, 23.82, 23.17, 23.68, 44932], [1508892840000, 23.62, 23.69, 23.3, 23.5, 87991], [1508892900000, 24.04, 24.34, 23.75, 24.07, 91442], [1508892960000, 23.95, 23.95, 23.25, 23.28, 34895], [1508893020000, 23.38, 23.66, 23.21, 23.34, 88422], [1508893080000, 23.45, 23.75, 23.36, 23.47, 65606], [1508893140000, 23.43, 23.92, 23.2, 23.79, 127863], [1508893200000, 23.57, 23.69, 23.32, 23.35, 81565], [1508893260000, 23.6, 24.03, 23.55, 23.86, 56219], [1508893320000, 23.97, 24.24, 23.63, 23.77, 89107], [1508893380000, 24.05, 24.3, 23.96, 24.04, 94978], [1508893440000, 23.76, 24.04, 23.21, 23.37, 83000]];
}
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-stock.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/fonts/css/anychart-font.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/css/anychart-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div id="container"></div>
```