# Having trouble with live streaming stock chart

Tags: live-streaming, candlestick-chart, anychart

I am trying to create a little trading simulator for my classroom but I'm pretty new to anychart.

I have a database of historical FOREX prices and I'd like to pull from that to create an initial chart up to a certain date/time and then pull from future quotes to simulate trading.

I found this post: [AnyChart - Live Streaming Stock Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374570/anychart-live-streaming-stock-chart)
which got me close but there's a few things I can't figure out.

Instead of randomly setting prices I'd like to use stored prices.  To keep it simple I tried creating a function with a simple 2d array with the desired prices.  It should be pretty simple to just pull the OHLC from that array but it's not clear where to put the numbers, I think I am getting confused by the code that does the random part (in the linked example)

Also, I can't seem to figure out how to change it to a candlestick chart, I've created other candlestick carts but something seems different about this one.  (Like I said, I'm new to anychart)

Here's the function I wrote to store and return the data values I eventually want returned:

type here

```
        var newData = [
         [23,23,21.85,22.87],
         [22.87,22.87,22.64,22.72],
         [22.72,23.63,21.58,21.69],
         [21.69,22.12,21.69,21.91],
         [21.91,23.01,21.47,22.14],
         [22.14,22.8,21.92,22.42],
         [22.42,23.32,21.3,23.31],
         [23.31,23.31,22.14,23.23],
         [23.23,23.23,23.23,23.23],
         [23.23,23.93,23.23,23.62],
         [23.62,24.56,23.38,24.22],
         [24.22,25.19,24.22,24.38],
         [24.38,25.6,23.4,23.82],
         [23.82,23.82,23.11,23.27],
         [23.27,24.2,22.11,23.93],
         [23.93,25.13,23.45,23.73],
         [23.73,24.92,23.73,24.13]
        ]
```

I can either set this up initially with a JSP or do something later to pull to the database.  I just don't understand what the linked example is doing well enough to know where to load these values directly

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, it will be a good idea to use the `addData()` method as well as include dates in your data. As demonstrated below:

```
table.addData([
        ['2015-12-25', 512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 507.34],              
        ['2015-12-26', 511.83, 514.98, 505.59, 506.23],
        ['2015-12-27', 511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 506.47],
        ['2015-12-28', 510.35, 515.72, 505.23, 505.80],
        ['2015-12-29', 510.53, 515.86, 505.38, 508.25],
        ['2015-12-30', 511.43, 515.98, 505.66, 507.45],
        ['2015-12-31', 511.50, 515.33, 505.99, 507.98],
        ['2016-01-01', 511.32, 514.29, 505.99, 506.37],
        ['2016-01-02', 511.70, 514.87, 506.18, 506.75],
        ['2016-01-03', 512.30, 514.78, 505.87, 508.67],
    ]);
```

We’ve compiled [a sample](https://playground.anychart.com/ZezhEBAl/1) for you to glimpse into, also, feel free to look into our [documentation on data for stock charts](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Data#data_as_array_of_arrays).